# Deploy cookie cutter websites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5, msdeploy

I'm working with a series of sites that all share the same back and middle tiers. The front-end has site-specific headers/footers, store email addresses and a few other app-specific settings.

I've never been exposed to the ways larger dev shops and automated deployments so the more common and obvious approaches will be right on over my head.

I'm trying to setup a scenario where, upon deployment, the new assemblies are propagated across each of the cookie cuttered sites with enough logic that each site applies the relevant settings.

Is this just a matter of laying out a series of MSBuild or PowerShell commands that iterate thru all settings for each site? Or perhaps databased values mapped to site-specific settings that are applied by code in the AppStart event?

thx

Answer (score 0):

If you use Web Deploy, you can create a package with parameters for certain components that will change at deploy time, and then specify values for those parameters when you deploy. The following resources have more information:

- [Customizing a Deployment Package](http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html)
- [Web Deploy Parameterization in Action](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html)
- [Web Deploy: Replace Rule vs. Parameterization](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2010/09/17/web-deploy-replace-rule-vs-parameterization.aspx)
- [Packaging and Deploying Web Applications for the Visual Studio Development Web Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/gg465162)
- [Team Build + Web Deployment + Web Deploy + VS 2010 = Goodness](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html)